# Excel Vba, if cell value start with specific value, delete from start value to next space, not all values in cell

Tags: excel

```
A COLUMN                   --> NEW A COULMN
CL123 R9873                     R9873  
CL1943 R0192 R01923             R0192 R01923
R1242 EWCVZWQEW                 WCVZWQEW 
R2012 NCL102820                 NCL102820
R3 DFK1KDKCLDDKD                DFK1KDKCLDDKD
0082 1923U83 2021               082 1923U83 2021
JWMK-MXM1I0284J                 JWMK-MXM1I0284J
12937820284                     12937820284
```

I want to make "new A column like above by coding in VBA"

Specific Start value : CL, R1, R2, R3 --> TOTAL : 4

If cell value's start is "CL" or "R1" or "R2" or "R3",
the value's in selected cell should be changed with deleting until next space. (as above)

Could you help me to make it??...
It is kind of hard to express....

Comment: Should be pretty easy to do with a formula... why do you need VBA?

Answer (score 0):

Have a try on below formula.

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A2,2)="CL",LEFT(A2,2)="R1",LEFT(A2,2)="R2",LEFT(A2,2)="R3"),TRIM(MID(A2,SEARCH(" ",A2),100)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank u so much!! it works!!

Comment: @NAVER.YSWOO Then please consider accepting the answer. Tick mark the answer as green.

Comment: YES! MY PLEASURE